# In Javascript, is it possible to give tab an active style when it only unhides a div, instead of loading a new page?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have Javascript tabs which show/hide divs instead of loading new pages. The tabs have a style which gives a hover effect. I now want to add an active style to match up with the curently visible div.

THE JAVASCRIPT, which does not work as it is from a version which loads pages:

```
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i < aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href) >= 0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}

function showdiv(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

function hidediv(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

THE STYLE:

```
#pageAdmin { display:block; }
#userAdmin { display:none; }
```

THE HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a onclick="showdiv('pageAdmin'); hidediv('userAdmin')" 
          href="#">Page Admin</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="showdiv('userAdmin'); hidediv('pageAdmin')" 
          href="#">User Admin</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="pageAdmin">
    <h1>Page admin</h1>
</div>

<div id="userAdmin">
    <h1>User admin</h1>
</div>
```

This is my first question on SO, so I hope it is appropriate - please accept my apologies in advance if it is not!

Answer (score 0):

Your setActive function isn't very helpful. And using location, href and hash it will be hard doing what you want.

You may change your script to

```
function showdiv(id){
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = "block";
  el.className = "active";
}

function hidediv(id){
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.display = "none";
  el.className = "";
}
```

Now it should do what you want.

However, you should take a look on [jQuery](http://jquery.com).
Using jQuery you do eliminate the use of getElementById and you can much simpler attach an eventhandler for onclick's, as by using vanilla js. It is considered as bad practice to setup handlers in html attributes.
jQuery also handles you the splitting and joining the space separated className string, if you want to use multiple styles.

Using jQuery it looks like:

```
$("a", "#nav").click(function () {
  var $navA = $(this);
  var tabName = $navA.attr("data-tabName");

  $(".tab").each(function () {
    var $tab = $(this);
    if ($tab.attr("id") === tabName) {
      $tab.css({ display: 'block' }); // you may move this into active style
      $tab.addClass("active");
      $tab.removeClass("inactive");
    }
    else {
      $tab.css({ display: 'none' }); // you may move this into inactive style
      $tab.removeClass("active");
      $tab.addClass("inactive");
    }
  });
});
```

The HTML for the jQuery example

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a data-tabName="pageAdmin" href="#">Page Admin</a></li>
    <li><a data-tabName="userAdmin" href="#">User Admin</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab" id="pageAdmin">
    <h1>Page admin</h1>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="userAdmin">
    <h1>User admin</h1>
</div>
```